# Compute the height with JavaScript of a long paragraph and Chrome / Chromium

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I want to calculate the height of a paragraph with JavaScript.

Basic example...

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

console.log(document.querySelector('p').offsetHeight);

console.log(document.querySelector('p').getBoundingClientRect());
```

Minimal reproductible example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h28ws3ox/)

Firefox (85.0.1) returns correct result (95 pixels).

Chromium (88.0) does not (72 pixels)! But Console > Computed > height returns correct result usually according to my tests.

How to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps there is some DOM manipulation being done prior to when you check  or possibly some image content?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Firefox and Chromium use different font-family by default.